# Install Barcode Scanner

Tags: android

Friends i am trying to develop a barcode scanner.
Working flow is as:
When user click on scan button, it should capture image of barcode , scan this image and show the result:
Problem is, when i click on scan button getting a message "install barcode scanner"
I don't want to use this approach.
What to change in my code????, here is my code.

```
    IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(BarcodeScanner.this);
    integrator.initiateScan();

    scan_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Barcode_Scan_Button);
    scan_btn.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent scanIntent= new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
            scanIntent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");

            startActivityForResult(scanIntent, 0);

        }
    });
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
      IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
      if (scanResult != null) {
          result_text.setText(intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT"));
      }
      else
          result_text.setText("Scan cancelled.");

    }

}
```

Comment: You are trying to call android barcode scanner, so if you don't want to use it you have to write your own scanner :)

Comment: Any idea to write my own scanner!!!???

Comment: sorry I don't, why don't you like that scanner ?

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing to change, you are calling an external BarcodeScanner application, namely the ZXing app. If it isn't present on your device, it will prompt you to install it.

If you don't like this behaviour, then you can either try writing your BarcodeScanner logic, or integrate the ZXing code in your application since it's open source, however I advice you not to do that, becuase that is not the purpose of the ZXing project.

Comment: Check out this tutorial http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/